# How to include span tags in an array?

Tags: reactjs

I think this question has been asked before but I couldn't find a satisfactory answer. I am building a page using React and I need to make some parts of the text bold. Normally I would do this using span tags but the problem is that the text is coming from an array. I tried including the span tag in the array by concatenation but I am getting a weird result. Anyone knows a workaround?

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xLti.png)
[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TWEn.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your string in a `p` tag like:

```html
<p>Bla bla bla <span>...</span></p>
```